# Databinding to mat-slide-toggle value inside of an *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

At the moment I have created a form that allows the user to create a layer (it will be just a name for an eventual leaflet layer). Whenever I do this the value will show true or false but the moment I add another slide toggle both of them will go to true or false.  I'm not sure how to apply the index in this situation.

html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addALayer(f)">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Layer Name" ngModel name="layername">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button mat-icon-button 
            color="accent"
      ><mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon></button>
</form>

</div>
  <div class="layerGroupings">
   <div *ngFor="let layer of layers; let i = index">
    <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="layeron"></mat-slide-toggle> {{layer}} {{ layeron }}
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
layers = [];
layeron: boolean;


addALayer(form: NgForm) {
this.layerName = form.value.layername;
this.layers.push(this.layerName);
}
```

Also what lifecycle hook would catch this change.  If I add a console.log(this.layeron) in the ngOnInit or even ngOnChanges nothing is registered in the console...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="layerGroupings">
   <div *ngFor="let layer of layers; let i = index">
    <mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="layeron[i]"></mat-slide-toggle> {{layer}} {{ layeron }}
   </div>
  </div>
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cazpib

Comment: I get a TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.  I have a feeling this is because my array is empty to begin with.

Comment: then set empty array like this  layeron=[];

Comment: Thankyou so much!  Would you happen to know which lifecycle hook would catch these changes?

Comment: angular change detection is detected using ngzone

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into the ngZone but I figured i can make it work by just listening to the (change) event on the slide-toggle.